# How can I leave loop when got correct result

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, cypress

I have loop that search for some name. 
Result returned as list on each entered character, when word found, I want to clic it and leave loop, but it starts over until use all chars from Name.

```
var genArr = name.split('')
        cy.wrap(genArr).each(($el, ind, $list) => {
            cy.get('parent').children('chils').type(genArr[ind]).then(()=>{
                cy.wait(0.5)
                if (ind > 2) {
                    cy.get('list').its('length').then((size) => {
                        if (size == 1) {
                            cy.get('list').eq(0).click()
                            //here I wish to stop .each()
                        }else if(ind==genArr.length&&size==0){
                            throw new Error('Search: name wasn\'t found')
                        }
                    })
                } 
            })  
        })
```

Comment: I'm just guessing: Would return; work?

Comment: nope with return i got this: 
```CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.
Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.
You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().
The value you synchronously returned was: 'true'```

Comment: just 'return;' skipped at all, loop continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to `return false` based on the documentation:

- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early